# Embedded awk syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a syntaxfile for highlighting awk embedded in bash script:

```
syn include @AWKScript syntax/awk.vim
syn region AWKScriptCode matchgroup=AWKCommand
    \ start=+[=\\]\@<!'+ skip=+\\'+ end=+'+ contains @AWKScript contained
syn region AWKScriptEmbedded matchgroup=AWKCommand
    \ start=+\<\(g\?awk\|\$AWK\)\>+ skip=+\\$+ end=+[=\\]\@<!'+me=e-1 
    \ contains=@shIdList,@shExprList2 nextgroup=AWKScriptCode
syn cluster shCommandSubList add=AWKScriptEmbedded
hi def link AWKCommand Type
```

The problem is with this section:

```
start=+\<\(g\?awk\|\$AWK\)\>+
```

It works fine for awk and gawk, but not for $AWK. How can I add a rule to match $AWK as a starting pattern for the AWKScriptEmbedded region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `$AWK` is already highlighted by the `shDerefSimple` syntax group, so your new region isn't applied. Split the syntax definition into two parts and add the `containedin=` for the latter:

```
syn region AWKScriptEmbedded matchgroup=AWKCommand
    \ start=+\<g\?awk\>+ skip=+\\$+ end=+[=\\]\@<!'+me=e-1
    \ contains=@shIdList,@shExprList2 nextgroup=AWKScriptCode
syn region AWKScriptEmbedded matchgroup=AWKCommand
    \ start=+\$AWK\>+ skip=+\\$+ end=+[=\\]\@<!'+me=e-1
    \ contains=@shIdList,@shExprList2 containedin=shDerefSimple nextgroup=AWKScriptCode
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Is this also why it won't work to include a \< in the start match, because it is contained in another region?