# Vim - proper handling of multiple syntax in a single shell script

Tags: awk, vim, syntax-error, vim-syntax-highlighting

I write many scripts where there is complex awk logic incorporated into the script directly.  I prefer the "one-stop-shop" approach and not have those logic segments as external files.

I have tried what I have seen in [**this reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601403/multiple-file-types-in-vim) about specifying the **multiple syntaxes** that are to be evaluated (*and hopefully colorized per syntax colorscheme*).  I tried the suggested method as both a VIM command and as a setting in the .vimrc file.  The use of "**setfiletype sh.awk.sed**" did not work in either case.

Is there a special way to make this work properly ?

Another [**reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913756/embedded-awk-syntax-highlighting-in-vim) seems to provide what looks like awk-related syntax declarations. However, those are presented out of context, and it is not clear if the info provided is complete and self-contained, or whether that is an extract from an unknown, unpublished larger syntax definition, and whether that is added to the sh.vim or the awk.vim syntax files ?

Can anyone shed light on this ?

This first image is a test file created to show my colorscheme use-cases for **Bourne shell**.

[image: first image]

This second image is a sample of **awk logic** displayed by the same scheme.

[image: second image]

Comment: [How do I navigate topics in Vims documentation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation). `:h sh-awk`.

Comment: starting with the first BEGIN, put all that in a filename.awk file and try vim on that.  It is getting confused by the " and ' on multiple lines

Comment: Thank you, Andrew.  When I worked professionally within a project team, I've done that a lot because that was the team preference.  My own preference for coding applicable to my desktop environment is to keep each task-oriented script as standalone and self-contained as possible, keeping it all together.  I read somewhere that Vim is supposed to handle multiple syntax simultaneously.  However, I haven't found any references outlining how to make that happen for bourne/bash shell and awk, which I have come to rely on more than in the past.  Any guidance on making that work would be appreciated.

Comment: @Eric Does this help?: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31896/how-to-syntax-highlight-part-of-a-file-in-a-foreign-language